# How to do a call to a webserive from a service class

Tags: android, service, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to use Push Notifications in my app. I have the work done, but now I need to send the refreshed tokens of Firebase to my own server, but I don't know how to use a rxjava2/retrofit2 method outside of the context of an activity/fragment. How I can access it?

My source:

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "FIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

        //TODO

    }

}
```

If I was in an activity/fragment I would use the next call, but in a service I can not do it.

```
getCompositeDisposable()
.add(productManager.getProductList(authToken))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Consumer<List<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull List<Product> products) throws Exception {
                        onProductsLoaded(products);
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        if (!isViewAttached())
                            return;
                        getMvpView().hideAlertDialog();
                        getMvpView().showErrorAlertDialog();
                    }
                }));
```

Comment: I am unable to understand what is hindering you to do it in Service.

Comment: Inside the method "void sendRegistrationToServer(String token)" I need to do a call to the rest service with the new token, to store the new token on the server side. But I don't know how to do a REST call without context of activity/fragment.

Comment: Well, I guess REST service call doesn't require context of Activity/Fragment

Comment: You should just remove `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` and remove ui related code from subscribe override methods. The same code block should work within service.

Answer (score 0):

To call a REST service, Activity/Fragment context is not required at all.

```
URL fireBaseUrl = new URL("http://your.service.url");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) fireBaseUrl.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + NetworkUtils.SERVER_KEY);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject()
                    .put("to", "/topics/skm")
                    //.put("to", NetworkUtils.REGISTRATION_TOKEN)
                    .put("data", new JSONObject()
                            .put("latitude", longitude)
                            .put("longitude", latitude));

            OutputStreamWriter oStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            String requestString = notification.toString();
            Log.d("JSON REQUEST", requestString);

            oStreamWriter.write(requestString);
            oStreamWriter.close();

            int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("STATUS CODE", status + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

After all, I create a new compositedisposable and a manager only for this service. And a request with this objects. I've needed to use the sharedpreferences to store de new push token.

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {

        Log.e("FIIS", "sendRegistrationToServer(" + token + ")");

        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

        AccountUserManager accountUserManager = new AccountUserManager();

        compositeDisposable
                .add(
                        accountUserManager
                                .updatePushToken(getUserAuthToken(), token)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(new Consumer<HttpCustomRes<EmptyModel>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(@NonNull HttpCustomRes<EmptyModel> emptyModelHttpCustomRes) throws Exception {

                                        ErrorCode errorCaught = ErrorCode.bypassForErrors(emptyModelHttpCustomRes.getError());

                                        if (errorCaught.equals(ErrorCode.SUCCESSFUL_REPSONSE)) {
                                            Log.e("FIIS", "SUCCESSFUL_RESPONSE");
                                            setUserPushToken(token);
                                        } else {
                                            Log.e("FIIS", "Unknown Error. Error " + errorCaught.getId());
                                        }

                                    }
                                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                        Log.e("FIIS", "Error. " + throwable.getMessage());
                                    }
                                }));

    }

    String getUserAuthToken() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        if (sharedPreferences.contains(AppConstants.PREF_KEY_USER_AUTH)) {
            String userAuthString = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.PREF_KEY_USER_AUTH, null);
            UserAuth userAuth = new Gson().fromJson(userAuthString, UserAuth.class);

            return userAuth.getToken();
        }

        return null;

    }

    void setUserPushToken(String token) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(token, null).apply();

    }
```